# regular expression, find string, exclude list of words containing string

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the string "isis" but I don't want a specific list that I know it will be in, such as "crisis"
I have tried this...^(?!(CRISIS|crisisid)$)[ISIS]+$ but that doesn't work, either.  the strings can be any case and/or mixed case.

Comment: Have you tried word boundaries ([`\bisis\b`](https://regex101.com/r/oN8rX0/1))? Case handling is probably better addressed by a case-insensitive regex function from whatever language you're using.

Comment: Is this the list of words that you want to exclude? i.e. `CRISIS`, `crisisid`, `ISIS`?

Comment: @excaza, I'm using a search function in my IDE, it's a MS product.

Comment: @ccf, I want to find "isis", upper/lower/mixed case.  The list of words I don't want to be returned are known words that contain "isis", such as lwcrisis, crisisid, etc.  again, the case is can be upper/lower/mixed.

Comment: Then go with @excaza 's pattern: `/(\bisis\b)/gi`

Comment: This is what I found that worked.  ^(?!(.*crisis.*|.*isisid.*)$).*ISIS.*  
XXISISIDXX  --> No  
FFFISISFFF  --> Yes  
NNCRISISNN  --> No  
ISIS  --> Yes  
XYZ  --> No  
XXX ISIS  CCC  --> Yes  
isisid  --> No  
lwisis  --> Yes

Comment: This uses a presearch, and I am finding the patterns of all words with 'crisis' and 'isisid'.  I want to exclude them from finding all other instances of 'isis'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found that worked.

```
^(?!(.*crisis.*|.*isisid.*)$).*ISIS.*
```

results in:

```
XXISISIDXX --> No 
FFFISISFFF --> Yes 
NNCRISISNN --> No 
ISIS --> Yes 
XYZ --> No 
XXX ISIS CCC --> Yes 
isisid --> No 
lwisis --> Yes
```